# Taking screenshot programatically is very slow

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code which takes about 7-10 seconds each time to load and I want to optimise it so it takes the screen shot and loads to be shared in a second or less.

```
UIImage *imageToShare = [self screenshot];
NSArray *activityItems = @[stringToShare, imageToShare];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];

- (UIImage *) screenshot {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

I'm not too sure how I can make this run quicker? Any ideas please?

Comment: Instead of 'drawViewHierarchyInRect' use 'renderInContext' on view's layer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `drawViewHierarchyInRect: afterScreenUpdates:` is heavy. I've always used `renderInContext:` to snapshot a view:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```